# Is there a better way to structure this MySQL query to make it run faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use a query to output a leaderboard. Where the output is sorted by the amount of commission earned by agents. I noticed that running the query takes quite a long time (+- 30 seconds). I was wondering if by like structuring (or ohter solutions) the query differently I could make the runtime faster.

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT agent, 
        COUNT(*) as sales, 
        (4*(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Sales Sales2 
        WHERE Sales2.agent=Sales.agent AND finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=117)) 
        / 
        (SELECT SUM(uren) 
        FROM Uren 
        WHERE datum BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND agent=Sales.agent) as sph, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Sales Sales3 
        WHERE Sales3.agent=Sales.agent AND finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-27 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=165) as telecom 
    FROM Sales 
    WHERE finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-27 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=117 
    GROUP BY agent ) r 
ORDER BY sales * sph * (case when sph > 1.5 then 10 else 7.5 end ) * 0.5184 + telecom * 3.75 desc;
```

This is the result of the EXPLAIN

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    165 100.00  Using filesort
2   DERIVED Sales   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14899   1.11    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  Sales3  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14899   0.11    Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  Uren    NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7286    1.11    Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  Sales2  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14899   0.11    Using where
```

Comment: execution plan needed, see: [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: It would also help to have sample data and the desired output from that data. There are probably much better ways to do this, but without the data it's hard to tell.

Comment: no indexes are being used, so 'some' indexes are missing.

Comment: Start by creating two indexes, the first on Sales with the fields `flow, finalized_at` and the second in Uren with the fieldd `flow, finalized_at`.   I am not sure about the order of the fields, they might be reversed, but without data this is hard to tell....

Comment: @Luuk. With adding the indexes I went from a running time of 27 seconds to 2,5 seconds. So it helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to trunc those dates so the database will only consider the full day, and by this, processing less information.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT agent, 
        COUNT(*) as sales, 
        (4*(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Sales Sales2 
        WHERE Sales2.agent=Sales.agent AND trunc(finalized_at) BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-27' AND flow=117)) 
        / 
        (SELECT SUM(uren) 
        FROM Uren 
        WHERE trunc(datum) BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-27' AND agent=Sales.agent) as sph, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Sales Sales3 
        WHERE Sales3.agent=Sales.agent AND trunc(finalized_at) = '2020-11-27' AND flow=165) as telecom 
    FROM Sales 
    WHERE trunc(finalized_at) = '2020-11-27' AND flow=117 
    GROUP BY agent ) r 
ORDER BY sales * sph * (case when sph > 1.5 then 10 else 7.5 end ) * 0.5184 + telecom * 3.75 desc;
```

This part:

```
  finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-27 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59'
```

Was changed to:

```
  trunc(finalized_at) = '2020-11-27'
```

Comment: But the database still needs to read the full datetime field? So how much faster do you think this will be ?

Comment: Functions never made nothing faster